# Transparent png tiles showing up weirdly in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, png, wmts

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running QGIS 2.6. I'm loading a raster layer, but the transparent PNG shows up poorly. The black lines along roads aren't showing up and the anti-aliasing looks off. I'm thinking that QGIS might be clipping the black values. I've fiddled with the raster settings but I can't get it to work. [Here's the original file.](http://b.tile.stamen.com/toposm-features/14/3375/6187.png)

[image: Transparent PNG looks fine in picture viewer, but not in QGIS]

With resampling changed to Bilinear

[image]

Comment: This can happen if your map is not the same coordinate system as the raster.  I assume that this is because transparency cannot be resampled the way other values can.

Answer (score 1):

The original file had 16 bit color bands. I saved the image to an 8 bit png and it worked fine. To diagnose the problem, I ran in terminal:

```
gdalinfo filename.png
```

The output is

```
....
Band 1 Block=256x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Red
....
```

The key is `Type=Uint16` Files with `Type=Byte` work just fine. So, the temporary solution is to just work with 8 bit files. Maybe someone knows how to get these to work?

Comment: Then perhaps there is a relation to this GDAL ticket http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5692. Fix is in GDAL trunk and will be included in GDAL 1.11.2 version to be released next week.

Comment: I think this is the problem. Notice how the black road lines goto clear/white and the the blue shoreline becomes green blocky red. I compiled the GDAL trunk version, but I'm not sure how to point QGIS to the new drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Change the resampling settings in the raster layer's properties from Nearest Neighbor to bilinear. That should create smoother results.

Comment: I have not had success resampling transparent png files, at least not through WM(T)S, which I assume the OP is using since the given example is a tile.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Changing to bilinear improves the picture, but adds blocky artifacts. I've added a picture to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Scro Yes, it is a tile service. Is there a way to turn off resampling? I do need the transparency though. My other tiles are loading fine like [these contour lines](http://a.tile.stamen.com/toposm-contours/13/1506/2880.png)

Comment: @Justin An image *must* be resampled if it is not used in its native projection. Briefly, your options seem to be: Change the CRS of your project to match the tiles; Find a source of tiles in your CRS; Find a source of tiles without transparency and place them lowest in layer order.

Comment: @Scro The problem seems to be that the source image has 16 bit single band colors. Images with 8 bit load just fine. Not sure if this a bug.